# Validation of paper-inputs that are not required

Tags: polymer

I am building a search request form, where the user may or may not fill in filter fields that he wants to narrow the search down by.  But if he does fill in a field I want to validate it.

For instance, this search form has a "date of birth" field, so if anything is entered into this field, I need to validate its a valid date.

Unfortunately, in single stepping through the code, a `<paper-input>` field that does not have the `required` attribute cannot be validated, yet if I do put a `required` attribute on the field, it checks for an empty string value before calling my validator and says the form is invalid if this happens to be one of the unused fields.

Is there anyway round this conundrum?

Comment: Have you tried using the `pattern` property together with `autoValidate` or the `validate()` method and the `allowedPattern` property as a bonus?

Comment: @Alan yes I have used and tried them, but they are insufficient for a sensible level of validation.  I can of course validate on the server, and return the results in an ajax response, but I was hoping to do better than that

Comment: What kind of validation are you doing?

Comment: The particular field I am working  on at the moment is a date of birth (formatted as dd/mm/yyyy - but of course less digits where appropriate), which I am have a allowedPattern of "[/0-9]", but with a custom validator which checks more fully the values for day month and year are within sensible ranges. I also will be checking fields for email and telephone numbers appropriate to the UK.

Comment: I think you could do all those validations with only regex though

Comment: Could you include a jsbin for a minimal reproduction of your use-case? It'll be much easier for others to help.